# Linq to entities with a multidimensional array as part of the query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

In LINQ to entities, I want to take the following sort of matrix(sorry about the top lines indenting) and query a different table, to check if given an input of (5) it only returns items with (F1,F2) of (1,1),(1,2) or (2,2)

```
    **F1**  1   2   3   4   5
**F2**                      
1       5   4   4   4   3
2       5   5   2   2   2
3       4   2   2   2   1
4       3   2   1   1   1
5       2   1   1   1   1
```

Unfortunately I hear Linq to entities doesnt like multidimensional arrays/dictionaries of tuples. Any ideas how I could do this? This is on a database hit and it needs to be before I call .ToList(){as it is a paged list}

**Edit:**
Okay so people didnt like my wording. So I have this mini structure that is stored in another database table(which I can convert to whatever format i need to but basically, "If Classification(F1) is 1, and Category(F2) is 1, then the output matrix says that the Rating is 5.
There is only ever one value for each combination of Classification and Category to output 1 rating, and I want to get items that have a particular rating, based on their Classification and Category.
Does that make sense sorry?

**Edit 2**

So I have a method, called "GetAllCars(int? rating,...) if rating has a value, I want to only return Cars with that rating from the database. but it needs to be calculated somehow. I have the lookup to get the value, but no way to parse it into linq to entities, because it doesnt support dictionaries or multidimensional arrays. So if I pass in a rating of 5, I want to somehow work out by the combination of the Classification and the Category if a car satisfies the rating, and return only those records from the database. This is a paged context, and i want to do the filtering BEFORE calling ToList on the context otherwise it will only filter the current page worth of data if that makes sense?

Comment: Could you show sample inputs and outputs. I find your question incomprehensible.

Comment: It would be good if you write down test cases with some samples that match your request. 
What is the correlation between 5 and [(1,1),(1,2),(2,2)]?

Comment: I have added additional wording, can add more if it still doesnt make sense

Comment: what does "check if given an input of (5)"  Or more specifically what operation/interaction does an input of 5 have with your "structure"

Comment: So I have a method, called "GetAllCars(int? rating,...)
if rating has a value, I want to only return Cars with that rating from the database. but it needs to be calculated somehow. I have the lookup to get the value, but no way to parse it into linq to entities, because it doesnt support dictionaries or multidimensional arrays.

Comment: So... What exactly is that you are asking or would like assistance with? If it is Linq that you are asking about, then please clearly state that and provide something you have tried (code) and the desired result

Comment: if the above structure is the target of your Linq query, then it is not Linq to Entities. If it is  are you asking: "what should the structure of my target so that I can query it using linq?"

Comment: Do you have an existing / working SQL query that you want to represent in linq? As a rule of thumb, if you can't write it in plain SQL, then linq to entities will also fail.

Comment: I COULD write it in SQL, but the problem is doing cross table queries, i could just See cars where the "calculated rating" is equal to the number I wanted it to be by checking the "Matrix" table. Unfortunately theres no association in the entity model to be able to do this query, and there can't be due to design constraints.

Comment: Well if you WOULD write the SQL to your question and also add your entity model classes, then there MIGHT be someone who can show you how to translate the query to linq or even how to configure a proper relation.